# Django: Performing a raw sql query with count()

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

I want to make a query to get the number of rows in the model MyTable that have the field expire (datetime) be a date in the current week.

In MySQL I execute the following query:

```
select count(expire) from MyTable where yearweek(expire) = yearweek(now());
```

So I can get the rows that belongs to the current week starting from Sunday. I tried replicate that using queryset in my view like this:

```
now = datetime.now()
myquery = MyTable.objects.filter(expire__year=now.year).filter(expire__week=now.isocalendar()[1])
```

But the thing is, Django method of querying starts from Monday, I want it for Sunday. So I though in doing a raw sql query Like this:

```
myquery = MyTabel.objects.raw('select count(expire) from MyTable where yearweek(expire) = yearweek(now());')
```

But it doesnt work, it doesnt output a value. How can I make this query?

I'm using mysql 5.7, python 3.7 and django 2.1.11
I know these are all old versions but I **can't** update.

Comment: Why not just use .count()?

Comment: rawquerysets does not support count() :/